# Meteor asynchronous call within Accounts.createUser

Tags: javascript, meteor

Before registering a new User I need to delete a previous one with that email and query an API to fill more information into User as a product requirement.

Unfortunately I can not achieve it, this is the error I get from the server: `Exception while invoking method 'createUser' Error: insert requires an argument`.

What I did so far is this:

Client:

```
Accounts.createUser({ email, password, profile: { something } }, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err2.reason);
  }
  history.replace('/account');
});
```

Server:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser((options, user) => {
  Meteor.users.remove({ email: options.email }, () => {
    try {
      const res = request.postSync(authenticate, {
        method: 'POST',
        json: true,
        body: {
          email: options.email,
          password: options.profile.password
        }
      });

      if (res.response.statusCode < 300) {
        const newUser = user;
        newUser.profile = {};
        newUser.profile.user_id = res.body.response.user_id;
        newUser.profile.token = res.body.response.token;
        return newUser;
      }

      throw new Meteor.Error(res.response.body.error.message);
    } catch (err) {
      throw new Meteor.Error(err.message);
    }
  });
});
```

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [`Accounts.onCreateUser` documentation](https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts-multi.html#AccountsServer-onCreateUser):

> The function should return the user document (either the one passed in or a newly-created object) with whatever modifications are desired. The returned document is inserted directly into the `Meteor.users` collection.

You function returns nothing though, it just calls `Meteor.users.remove()` with some function as second argument. Don't forget that DB calls are *synchronous* in Meteor, so it should be like this:

```js
Accounts.onCreateUser((options, user) => {
  Meteor.users.remove({ email: options.email });
  // do something else
  return user;
});
```